# setting the value on formik text field based on drop down select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, formik

I have one form in `formik` in `react`. it has 2 field one dropdown list and one input field. dropdown is getting populated from API. my requirement is when user selects any value in dropdown corresponding to that value `address` field gets populated.

[image]

I am populating list based on API call.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    fetchStatus();
},[]);

const fetchStatus = async ()=>{
   const {data}= await httpClient.get( config.resourceServerUrl+"/sponsors");
       if(data.length>0){
       setResult(data);
       setActive(true);  
   } 
}
```

below code is `select`.

```
                                  <div>
                                    <Field
                                        as="select"
                                        id="sponsor" 
                                        name="sponsor"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Sponsor"
                                        onChange={ (e:any)=>{  
                                            setFieldValue("address","Dummy Address");  
                                        }

                                        } >
                                        <option value="">Please select the 
                                              sponsor</option>
                                      {
                                         active && result.map((res:any)=>
                                              <option >{res.name}</option>
                                          )
                                      }
                                       </Field> 
                                </div>
```

when I am putting below in my `select` field to set `address` its working but its static. I want my data to get populated from API based on the  value selected in list.

```
                                   onChange={ (e:any)=>{  
                                        setFieldValue("address","Dummy Address");  
                                    }
```

[image]

instead of this `"Dummy Address"` how can I put `API` data?

below is my `address` field.

```
                                 <td>
                                        <Field
                                            id="address"
                                            name="address"
                                            type="text"
                                            className="form-control "
                                            placeholder="Address"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span className={styles.mandatory}>
                                        <ErrorMessage name="address" />
                                    </span>
                                </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a 'sponsor' value is selected, you want to set the value of the 'address' field (based on the 'sponsor' value).

You can probably get the value of the 'sponsor' field from the 'event' (here denoted as `e`) argument of the `onChange` function of the `<select>` element :

```
onChange={(e) => {  
  const sponsor = e.target.value;

  // rest of your code
}
```

Another way would be to use the `useEffect` hook to set the value of the 'address' and have 'sponsor' in the dependency array. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // make API call to fetch 'address' from 'sponsor' value

  // set 'address' value 
}, [sponsor])
```

Comment: can you help me bit more please? I mean how I can make the relation between address and selected value in list? both the field are coming from API?

Comment: in useEffect we can not do anything other then loading data. because this fileds needs to be populated once user select the value. and data is already loaded at the beginning

Comment: You can do more than 'loading data' w/ `useEffect`. You can perform [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) in your components. In addition, you can utilize the dependency array to only (try to) perform those side effects when specific variables change their value (Read: [skipping effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)). This is what I am trying to do in the 2nd code snippet of my answer. I want to leave the details of implementation (with `formik`) up to you .